# Bitbucket LFS Permission denied (SSH command)

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, ssh, git-lfs

I have a bash script that run commands on a windows machine (lets call it machine A) to pull a repository on bitbucket (using git) and then run specific programs to work on the pulled content.

I have also a ubuntu machine running Jenkins. On a build step I use the "Publish Over SSH" plugin to run the bash script on the machine A.

Everything goes fine all the times unless git has to pull a commit containing a large file and its fails with this error :

> Downloading test x_map.fbx (31 MB) Error downloading object: x_map.fbx (63b3f85): Smudge error: Error downloading x_map.fb x
>   (hash): batch request: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).:
>   exit status 255

The problem is that the LFS part of git doesn't use the SSH key even though I did set the core.sshCommand in git config to use a key for all the ssh commands.

So when I do this :
ssh git@bitbucket.org git-lfs-authenticate "reopsitory" downlaod
its fails with this message : git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey)

But it works fine when I run it with the ssh key option :
ssh -i "ssh-key-path" git@bitbucket.org git-lfs-authenticate "reopsitory" downlaod

So I was wondering if there was any solution to kind of overload all the LFS ssh commands to use a specific ssh key like the core.sshCommand in git config.

I m hardly stuck on this so I hope you guys have a miraculous solution! Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT :
adding prior to the git pull command :
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add "key-path" makes this command work : [  ssh git@bitbucket.org git-lfs-authenticate "reopsitory" downlaod ] but the git pull still fails with the same error

Comment: 1) Does re-cloning the project from Bitbucket properly fetch LFS objects? 2) What's the content of `.git/config`? 3) Are you cloning the project using a trailing slash in the URL? Have you tried removing the trailing slash?